# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [xyz] was terminated due to ORPHAN error using Zalenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, zalenium

When i run tests on my zalenium box i am getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [f70ab10a7e72f822cd26b73754bd2a2d] was terminated due to ORPHAN
```

What should i do to fix the problem? Is it a network issue?

It happens mostly when i have to navigate to an url on google chrome.
This is the error log:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [f70ab10a7e72f822cd26b73754bd2a2d] was terminated due to ORPHAN
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'bd0d6724cd03', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-139-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 76.0.3809.132, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 76.0.3809.126 (d80a294506b4..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.OrnJVy}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:44275}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept, webdriver.remote.sessionid: f70ab10a7e72f822cd26b73754b...}
Session ID: f70ab10a7e72f822cd26b73754bd2a2d
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:853)
at main.java.engine.web.mrd_Food.LoginPage_Food.navigateTo(LoginPage_Food.java:36)
at main.java.engine.web.mrd_Food.LoginPage_Food.login(LoginPage_Food.java:23)
at web.MrDFoodTest.LoginToMrDFood(MrDFoodTest.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1204)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:139)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:89)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:123)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [f70ab10a7e72f822cd26b73754bd2a2d] was terminated due to ORPHAN
```

...implies that the **Zalenium** ended the inactive session as being **ORPHAN**.

In the discussion [Session terminated due to ORPHAN](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/469) @diemol [mentioned](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/issues/469#issuecomment-371417340):

> Zalenium ends inactive sessions when they reach 90 seconds (default value).

Again, as per the documentation of [ZALENIUM](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/#usage):

> By default, Zalenium allows a test to be idle up to **90** seconds. After that elapsed time, the session will be terminated, the node will be shutdown and the recorded video will be saved (if video recording is enabled). This prevents a test to run indefinitely after something went wrong. If you need to have a longer *idle timeout*, just set an `idleTimeout` capability in your test:

This timeout can be configured through the capability **`idleTimeout`** as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.FIREFOX);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.LINUX);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout", 150);
```